# Is it possible to configure codahale @Timed to report a subset of it's default metrics?

Tags: java, spring, codahale-metrics

I am using codahale metrics' @Timed annotation with a graphite reporter in a spring app, but I only want to send a subset of the metrics to our graphite server.

For example, I have no need for p999, so removing that would reduce the sum of the number of metrics by the number of @Timed instances x number of environments.

I don't see how to do this from the API docs, and I don't see any examples of this.  Is this possible via metrics-spring config or via codahale's config?

Thanks!

-neil